# Using RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier(XMLUnit)

Tags: java, unit-testing, xmlunit

I need to compare two XML files where both have different order of entities.

```
 <root> 
  <parent1> 
   <parent2> 
     <value>1</value>  
   </parent2> 
   <parent2> 
    <value>2</value>  
   </parent2> 
  </parent1>  
  <parent1> 
   <parent2> 
     <value>3</value>  
   </parent2> 
   <parent2> 
     <value>4</value>  
   </parent2> 
  </parent1> 
</root>
```

As in the above example, if I swap the position of 1 and 2 in the other xml file, the test should pass. I am using `diff.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier())` for this purpose but it keeps failing the test!

Could you please advise on what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

`RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` works for a very specific use case, that's why we've never promoted it out of the `examples` package.

It tells XMLUnit to compare element `a` and element `b` if (and only if) their element names match and their nested texts are the same and all their child nodes also qualify using `RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` *in the order they appear as children*.

In your example if you swap `1` and `2` the very first `parent1` element will no longer qualify as its children don't qualify using the strict order.

What you need is a specialized `ElementQualifier` implementation as no built-in qualifier does exactly what you want.